# Android: How to use AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-1.5-cupcake

I need to trigger a block of code after 20 minutes from the `AlarmManager` being set.

Can someone show me sample code on how to use an `AlarmManager` in ِAndroid?

I have been playing around with some code for a few days and it just won't work.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

"Some sample code" is not that easy when it comes to `AlarmManager`.

Here is a snippet showing the setup of `AlarmManager`:

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);
```

In this example, I am using `setRepeating()`. If you want a one-shot alarm, you would just use `set()`. Be sure to give the time for the alarm to start in the same time base as you use in the initial parameter to `set()`. In my example above, I am using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, so my time base is `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

[Here is a larger sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled) showing this technique.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for the reply. If I purchase your book does it explain how to implement a alarm manager in full detail?

Comment: The Advanced Android book (Version 0.9) has ~9 pages covering AlarmManager, WakeLocks, and the rest of that example. That will probably expand slightly in Version 1.0 as I make the fix I mentioned in my answer above. And if you have questions regarding the book or its sample code, hop over to http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android and I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Any android developer should have subscription to Mark's books :) At least once

Comment: @MarioGalván: You need to set it when your app is run for the first time and on a reboot.

Comment: I think you should use AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP if you want it to fire right away and then every PERIOD. In your code, it will fire after SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() and then every PERIOD.

Comment: @DamonYuan: You are incorrect. That is equivalent of thinking that `RTC_WAKEUP`, with a value of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, will not invoke the alarm for ~46 years (the difference in time between now and 1 January 1970). The second parameter to `setRepeating()` is the time in the stated timebase when the alarm should go off.

Answer (score 69):

There are some good examples in the android sample code

> .\android-sdk\samples\android-10\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app

The ones to check out are:

- AlarmController.java
- OneShotAlarm.java

First of, you need a receiver, something that can listen to your alarm when it is triggered. Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver" />
```

Then, create the following class

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Then, to trigger an alarm, use the following (for instance in your main activity):

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

.

---

Or, better yet, make a class that handles it all and use it like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
// add extras here..
MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm(this, bundle, 30);
```

this way, you have it all in one place (don't forget to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`)

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String REMINDER_BUNDLE = "MyReminderBundle"; 

    // this constructor is called by the alarm manager.
    public MyAlarm(){ }

    // you can use this constructor to create the alarm. 
    //  Just pass in the main activity as the context, 
    //  any extras you'd like to get later when triggered 
    //  and the timeout
     public MyAlarm(Context context, Bundle extras, int timeoutInSeconds){
         AlarmManager alarmMgr = 
             (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
         intent.putExtra(REMINDER_BUNDLE, extras);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent =
             PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 
             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
         time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
         time.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeoutInSeconds);
         alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),
                      pendingIntent);
     }

      @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // here you can get the extras you passed in when creating the alarm
         //intent.getBundleExtra(REMINDER_BUNDLE));

         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I tested this code and it worsk fine (+1). but I tried this for multiple alarms (like one for 10 secons, and another for 15, and only the sencond one is fired. Am I doing somehting wrong, or is it some king of problem?
EDIT: Ok, I found the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844274/multiple-calls-to-alarmmanager-setrepeating-deliver-the-same-intent-pendinginten

Comment: FWIW, I would use a static method rather than a constructor for this.

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do is first create the intent you need to schedule. Then obtain the pendingIntent of that intent. You can schedule activities, services and broadcasts. **To schedule an activity e.g MyActivity:**

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),3333,i,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Give this pendingIntent to alarmManager:

```
  //getting current time and add 5 seconds in it
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
  //registering our pending intent with alarmmanager
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Now MyActivity will be **launched after 5 seconds of the application launch, no matter you stop your application or device went in sleep state** (due to RTC_WAKEUP option).
You can read complete example code [Scheduling activities, services and broadcasts #Android](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/06/scheduling-activities-services-and.html)

Comment: +1 great answer ,exactly what i needed ,
a working 'set' example.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to comment but <50 rep, so here goes. Friendly reminder that if you're running on 5.1 or above and you use an interval of less than a minute, this happens:

```
Suspiciously short interval 5000 millis; expanding to 60 seconds
```

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244).

Answer (score 3):

Some sample code when you want to call a service from the Alarmmanager:

```
PendingIntent pi;
AlarmManager mgr;
mgr = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(DataCollectionActivity.this, HUJIDataCollectionService.class);    
pi = PendingIntent.getService(DataCollectionActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 1000, pi);
```

You dont have to ask userpermissions.

Comment: A very common abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

An AlarmManager is used to trigger some code at a specific time.

To start an Alarm Manager you need to first get the instance from the System. Then pass the PendingIntent which would get executed at a future time that you specify

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
int interval = 8000; //repeat interval
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

You need to be careful while using the Alarm Manager.
Normally, an alarm manager cannot repeat before a minute. Also in low power mode, the duration can increase to up to 15 minutes.