# Multiple calls to AlarmManager.setRepeating deliver the same Intent/PendingIntent extra values, but I supplied different ones

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, extras, alarms

Solved while writing this question, but posting in case it helps anyone:

I'm setting multiple alarms like this, with different values of `id`:

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(
        Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(MyReceiver.ACTION_ALARM);  // "com.example.ALARM"
i.putExtra(MyReceiver.EXTRA_ID, id);  // "com.example.ID", 2
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextMillis, 300000, p);  // 5 mins
```

...and receiving them like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_ALARM)) {
        // It's time to sound/show an alarm
        final long id = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
```

The alarm is delivered to my receiver at the right times, but often with `EXTRA_ID` set to the wrong value: it's a value that I have used at some point, just not the one that I wanted delivered at that particular time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation for `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` says:

> **Returns**
>
> Returns an existing or new PendingIntent matching the given parameters.

The problem is that two Intents differing only in extras seem to match for this purpose. So `getBroadcast()` will return some random old PendingIntent (with a different `EXTRA_ID`) instead of a new one around the Intent I just created. The fix is to supply a data Uri and make it differ with the id, like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyReceiver.ACTION_ALARM, Uri.parse("timer:"+id));
```

You can then retrieve the id number using:

```
Long.parseLong(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart());
```

...or of course supply the extra as well and use that.

Comment: Just wondering, if I new an intent with 
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Cls);
Do I have this mixed id problem? In my case, the Cls is different for different Alarms. It should be OK, right?

Comment: I currently can't find the exact place I looked before to see the point about extras, but yes, with a different class it's a completely different Intent so I would very much expect that to work.

Comment: @ChrisBoyle, Thanks very much. But in my case, it doesn't work. However this works: `Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse(Long.toString(id)), context, AlarmActivity.class);`. Note that I can use activity.

Comment: After adding this line my AlarmReceiver(Broadcast Receiver) doesnt work at all. I want to set multiple alarms at a single point of time. Can I get some help? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

```
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

this should the work too

Comment: If you were only going to use it once at a time, then yes, but for an alarm with multiple timers set, you need multiple PendingIntents to be valid concurrently, and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT would leave you with all alarms sending the single most recent Intent.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for your problem is use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
  p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```