# AlarmManager.RTC doing too many updates on wakeup

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've got a service that I run every 30 minutes via `AlarmManager.RTC`. If the device is asleep long enough for the service to be called twice (and thus have both of them be rescsheduled), when it wakes up, it fires off the service twice at once.

The desired behavior is for the `AlarmManager` to just fire off one `Intent` when it wakes up. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you cancel the old one of Alarm Manager. If no means, just cancel the old one with `PendingIntent`

Have a look at this [Commonsware Example](http://www.ziddu.com/download/18064684/Alarm.zip.html)

Comment: How do I 'get' the old `PendingIntent`, and how do I cancel it? I want to make sure I preserve the existing scheduling of the intents, ie I dont want to cancel future intents.

Comment: @galaxyinfinite If two `PendingIntent`s were created in the exact same way, it's treated as the same one for `cancel()` and so on.  See the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: @izkata Where would I do the cancelling? From within the service that it has started? Like I said, then I'd need to reschedule my `PendingIntent`, which seems like a hack. Additionally, are the alarms scheduled in parallel? Then I wouldn't have a guarantee that it would do anything at all.

Comment: @galaxyinfinite See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707656/what-happens-when-i-start-an-alarm-twice - if the `PendingIntent`s are defined the same, they won't be scheduled twice.

Comment: @izkata, I read that as well, but I'm not getting that behavior. Even with `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` my intent gets scheduled again as described.