# Send data to the alarm manager broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am missing something here and I hope someone can help me out. I am setting up an alarm using the following:

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  broadcast_intent, 0);

    broadcast_intent.putExtra("test", "ValueReceived"); //data to pass
    Date date = someVariable.getDateTime();


    long triggerAtTime = date.getTime();

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, pendingIntent);
```

and the broadcast receiver using the following:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm has been received "+intent.getStringExtra("test"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

However intent s apperently "empty". I am seeing null value for the getStringExtra. So the data is not being passed to the broadcast receiver. What am  I doing wrong? How can I pass data.

Thank you so much

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844274/multiple-calls-to-alarmmanager-setrepeating-deliver-the-same-intent-pendinginten

Comment: see the answer from @Theus i think thats the one you need

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add the extras to the Intent **before** you pass it to the PendingIntent:

```
Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
broadcast_intent.putExtra("test", "ValueReceived"); //data to pass

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  broadcast_intent, 0);
```

Comment: i thinks this one might help you, assign first the extra before you psas it to the pending intent

Comment: Great it works wowww, I didn't know order matters as its the same object. I thank u