# Send notification id to receiver while set alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I try to set an alarm depending user chocies while setting alarm i want to send that alarm's unique notification id to reciever.java. I want to get data by this id on reciever.java.

I have a form with this form users are adding their pills and I'm saving every pill in different xml files for example pill1.xml pill2.xml. That saved pills have alarm and notification when alarm time came for example pill2.xml i will show pill2 datas in notirifacation bar.

that code on bottom is how i create alarm.

```
Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(ilac_hatirlatma.this, hatirlatma_detay.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ilac_hatirlatma.this, NOTIF_ID, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

reciever.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    createNotification(context, "İlaç Hatırlatma", "8 saatte bir içmeniz gereken 'Arvelez' adlı ilacınız bulunmaktadır.", "İlacınzı Almayı Unutmayınız!");

}

public void  createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert){

    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, ilac_hatirlatma.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon).setContentTitle(msg).setTicker(msgAlert).setContentText(msgText);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Can you not just store it in the SharedPreferences and access it from receiver.java?

Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: Ok. I have a form with this form users are adding their pills and I'm saving every pill in different xml files for example pill1.xml pill2.xml. That saved pills have alarm and notification when alarm time came for example pill2.xml i will show pill2 datas in notirifacation bar.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i prepare the alarm manager, every day at same hour

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at some time.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        // Checking whether current hour is over 15
        if (curHr >= 15)
        {
            // Since current hour is over 15, setting the date to the next day
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);


        // every day
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And here i have the BroadcastReceiver that generate the notification

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //Partial_wake_lock only need CPU active
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");

    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    int mId = 0;
    //Show the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_edit)
                    .setContentTitle("YOUR APP NAME")
                    .setContentText("TAKE THE PILLS!")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(-1);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
}
}
```

The permissions of the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

And Receiver declaration in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

For setting your Alarm manager read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

If you need to pass data between AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver use `.putExtra()` like how this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470453/send-data-to-the-alarm-manager-broadcast-receiver) explain
Hope this helps!