# Alarm clock like services

Tags: android

I want to develop an alarm clock like services in android that is the app should run on the some user entered time and even if the mobile is switched of that app should work as alarm clock works .

Answer (score 4):

Use an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager). You'll also probably want to recreate your alarms on reboot (they're normally cleared then); see this [android developers thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dc7b365e8d293708).