# Connect via Bluetooth every 20 minutes

Tags: android, bluetooth, scheduling

Is there a way to make an android app where: When the phone is idle, the phone wakes up for a minute, connects to a bluetooth device, receives/sends information to the device, processes some information and then goes back to idle mode (both cpu and the bluetooth radio shuts off), repeating this process every 20 mins?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty drastic battery drainer..

Comment: yeah...i know..but i want the most efficient way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may require the functionality in [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Also, refer to this question here on SO for some example code: [Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager).