# Trigger a notification every x days

Tags: android, notifications

I want to trigger a notification in the status bar every x days(that the user will define in the application). How can i code this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) was designed for stuff like that.

Comment: Is there please some samples ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know how to code an android app, you can see these pages for code examples:

1. To trigger a notification in the status bar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
2. To run the trigger evey x days, you can use AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: The problem is there is just this parameters: INTERVAL_DAY 
INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES INTERVAL_HALF_DAY INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR INTERVAL_HOUR. There is no customized value.

Comment: Aha. Well they are constants. So for example if you need two days you say 2*INTERVAL_DAY, if you need 3.5 days you say 3.5*INTERVAL_DAY.

Comment: Okay. And i've found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager and i don't know what OnAlarmReceiver.class contains :\. Any idea please ?

Comment: From the look of it, it extends BroadcastReceiver and overrides the onReceive method to run something - status bar notice in your case.  Here is a more detailed explaination of how to use AlarmManager: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#pendingintent