# Reload current activity every 10 mins

Tags: java, android, timer, reload

I am not sure the best way to accomplish this but I would like to reload my app's current activity every 10 mins. So I can show the most current data.

If there is some timer class I can create to run a method every 10mins that does the following:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

My Main reason for doing this is to reload so the activity does the http call again gets the data and adds it to a list view and gives the effect of it UPDATING every 10 mins.

Comment: But why do you need to show the activity every 10 minutes? You could update in a background thread/service without the user knowing anything. When the user opens the activity, he will see the latest info.

Comment: you don't need to actually restart your activity. you could just, like, update it. Also 10 minutes is an eternity in a mobile app.

Comment: don't kill and recreate the activity, start a backgroundthread and update your activity with a listener

Comment: @njzk2 this is for a tablet and it will be a fixture so the activity will always be on.

Comment: don't restart your activity if you don't _really_ need to, which you don't. use alarmmanager if you need a timer that won't consume anything on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the updating `listview` you do not need to start the activity again. it will be bad user exeperience. you can put that in the `timertask` and for every  10 mins call the HTTP call function and set the `adapter` in the same function.. you work is over.

Comment: sounds like exactly what I am looking for. I will try that now.

Answer (score 1):

Use AlarmManager, TimerTask i don't think is the best approach.

You can check a snippet here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082836/327011