# update sqlite database based on time interval android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know how to update sqlite DB based on time interval provided by user. I need to update location manager based on time interval in android application and update my data every time sqlite based on time interval.

Any sample code will be of great use to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use CountDownTimer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html  or timer service from which you can call the query for the regular interval of the time

Answer (score 0):

I have given one related answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666930/android-is-it-possible-to-create-a-database-and-save-some-information-in-it-eve/8667240#8667240)** , It may help you.