# Creating my own alarmclock Activity

Tags: android, android-alarms

im trying to create an alarm clock application which do a spesific actions once the alarm goes off and im running into some troubles:

first, i was playing around with the AlarmClock() class, which has few values i can set-up

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, tpSetClock.getCurrentHour());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, tpSetClock.getCurrentMinute());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        startActivity(i);
```

i would also like to modify the repeat and ringtone of the alarm, can it be set through AlarmClock()?

now after skipping the UI of the alarm clock i want to launch my own Activity once the alarm trigger comes in, how do i do that?

thanks in advance, yotam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `AlarmManager` to display your own activity or perform any other action. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager) contains a bunch of usage examples.