# Android AlarmManager fails to work

Tags: android, alarmmanager

According to my knowledge, I should see the log "Alarm" in the Logcat after 20 seconds from starting the application, but it is not happening. What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 1);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 20000, pendingIntent);

        Log.d("alarm", "alarm");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you should use

```
getActivity (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

As your `Intent` specifies the activity class, not service. Next, the last parameter (flags) can have values from constants in `PendingIntent` class. And as mentioned, second paramter should be `0` as it not used currently. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager) question for sample usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

The third parameter is currently not used.Check [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)