# How to obtain system time and update data from database automatically with an amount of time

Tags: android

I'm a new Android dev and I'm currently developing an app which is to display ListView data from web database.

But what I want is to update the data based on system time.

Let's say right now displaying data from database:

1. lalala
2. lololo
3. wewewe

and I need to update these data automatically FROM the database every 24 hours so that the outcome will be:

1. lilili
2. wowowo
3. popopo

I've tried System.currentTimeMillis(), it does not return any values.

Any professional out there could help me out ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

this.runOnUiThread(); of Your Activity can help you in this. This method updates itself after every second. What you should have to do is to pass a runnable as a parameter. Now in this runnable you can update your data. You can have a check in this runnable for 24 hours.

Regards

Comment: He should probably use the alarm manager instead of a runnable - depending on his needs. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager.