# AlarmManager.setRepeating() in Android not setting off alarm

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm having a problem with setting an alarm using setRepeating().

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("id", storable.getId());
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, storable.getId(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, storable.getObject().getTimeOnDay(Calendar.FRIDAY), Event.MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY*7, pi);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(storable.getObject().getTimeOnDay(Calendar.FRIDAY));
Log.v("ACTUALLY SCHEDULED ON FRIDAY", c.getTime().toString());
```

Logcat states: 09-28 02:17:58.535: V/ACTUALLY SCHEDULED ON FRIDAY(32494): Fri Oct 05 01:43:00 EDT 2012

which is the correct time that I scheduled. However, my alarm does not trigger. The only clue I have as to what may be causing this is that when i step into the method using the debugger, one of the methods that is called is Parcel.readException(). I do not know what this means or if it is even actually important. Does anybody have a clue what might be going on?

Comment: Hi, show your OnAlarmReceiver class

Comment: public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // do some work
    }
}

I am sorry I can't get it to indent properly :/ Do you need any more?

Comment: This is never being called. In case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Have you added OnAlarmReceiver into AndroidManifest?

Comment: yes. and another function that calls mgr.set() on a nearly identical PendingIntent runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager) link. It was also asked by Tom and CommonsWare gave a pretty good answer to that.

**EDIT:**

See if this helps:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: This is the code that i used to build this code and it is almost exactly the same except I use system time instead of elapsed time and so my first flag parameter is different.

Comment: This code is almost exactly the same as the code thats implemented (Calendar.add() is done in getTimeOnDay().) The time is correct I am positive from the log.

Comment: Then have you registered your Receiver in Manifest file...because I am getting desired output from this code..!!

Comment: That is very strange. I have the line

 <receiver android:name=".scheduling.OnAlarmReceiver" >
        </receiver>
in my code and other methods call this reciever that work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This method was being called multiple times, and using the same value from storable.getId() in the PendingIntent. It was overwriting the old PendingIntent and scheduling another one that I did not wait for. Thanks to those of you who helped.