# android application running in background

Tags: android, multithreading, background

I am building an app on android that basically reads the contents of a file and displays them as a pop up, at regular intervals, running itself in the background, say, it runs in the background all the time and displays the contents of the file every 2 hrs.

How can I impement this?

I am new to the android programming, so please help me with some examples.
thank you

Comment: You really cannot expect the community to find solutions or do research for you. You find the examples and ask a question if you are stuck somewhere in your program.

Comment: excuse me sir ,
I was not asking the code for the whole program.It was just a request that if anyone replies with a certain option to perform the required function, please provide any link or something, that contains any examples on how to use that option, because I am a newbie in this filed and I didn'd find any useful links till now that explained how to perform the required functionality.That's it.
As a senior user, I don't think you are expected to be that rude.

Comment: 1. I was not being rude. 2. As a new user, you are expected to go through the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) of a forum. It can be difficult getting started with a new platform. I was there too. And I am still learning. But SO has a few guidelines that have to be followed. We expect objective question backed by some effort from you. And as user with a decent rep, it also is kind of a responsibility to help keep SO questions to the point and as per the _rules_ set up. And like several tenured and responsible users, I am just playing my part.

Comment: ok, I am sorry for what I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at androids alarm manager, which will help you scedual your popups

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

[Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

Comment: can I send different data on each call to alarm manager?