# Cannot restart AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to make an AlarmManager which starts when the Screen is woken up and unlocked and stops, when . After each unlock the Timer should be resetted. This code works fine, but just one time. I could cancel it and then restart it, but once the Alarm Manager has been counted down it will not restart again.

```java
public class OnOffReceiver extends Service {

PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent myIntent = null;
Calendar calendar;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("", "Receiver service starts now");

    StartAlarmManager();

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Log.v("", intent.getAction());

              pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(OnOffReceiver.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
              alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

              alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); 

          }
        }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));


    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Log.v("", intent.getAction());
              StartAlarmManager();
          }
        }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT));

    return START_STICKY;
}

final void StartAlarmManager() {
    try {
        myIntent = new Intent(OnOffReceiver.this, SoundService.class);
        Looper.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Log.v("", "Trying to start AlarmManager");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(OnOffReceiver.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);               
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("", "Receiver service successfully ended");
}   
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `cancel()` doesn't work as expected? And why are you doing this from a service?

Comment: I'm using a service, because I want a background activity. The `cancel()` is working fine, I could cancel the AlarmManager as many times as I want to. Nevertheless once the AlarmMAnager has been triggered and the 10 seconds have passed away, the AlarmManager hadn't started again.

Comment: `set()` only triggers a single alarm. If you want repeating alarms you have to use `setRepeating()` or set new alarms manually. Ideally a service shouldn't care if the screen is off or on, because by definition it runs in the background. What are trying to achieve on a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `setRepeating` function that's part of the `AlarmManager` class:

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),  PERIOD, pi);
```

where `PERIOD` is the interval between alarm instances. For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager) question.