# Android Alarm on if Statement

Tags: java, android, google-maps, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to sound an alarm and turn it off with a dialog button when an if statement is met.

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
    new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            LatLng clickedMarkerLatLng = marker.getPosition();
            lat =  clickedMarkerLatLng.latitude;
            long1 =  clickedMarkerLatLng.longitude;
            String name = marker.getTitle();
            select=true;

            final Location markerLoc = new Location("");
            markerLoc.setLatitude(lat);
            markerLoc.setLongitude(long1);


            final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);   

            float distanceBetweenPoints = location.distanceTo(markerLoc);

            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            t.setText("Distance to "+ name +" is "+ distanceBetweenPoints/1000 + " km");

            if (distanceBetweenPoints<1000){
            TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            t2.setText("ALARMALARMALARM");
            //alarm here

        }
    });
```

Everything I've found about Alarm Manager doesn't seem to let me use it in the if statement. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `t.setText` is working or not ? if yes then use log to check if statement is executing or not

Comment: the if statement works fine, i've checked that far. I'm just unsure of how to implement an alarm within that if statement

Comment: This might help. : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager**