# setng alarm using AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want alarm service to broadcast a intent every 1 hr.

I do it using RTC_WAKEUP as follows:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmSheduleHelper
                .getImmediateNextHour().getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

Now i want to do it using ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP .How can i do it?

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, ELAPSED_TIME_REAL_OF_STARTING_HR, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

How do i get `ELAPSED_TIME_REAL_OF_STARTING_HR` ie elapsedRealtime correspoding to starting hr?

Answer (score 2):

there is no ELAPSED_TIME_REAL_OF_STARTING_HR flag in android system, and you have to specify the start time of alarm in place of this flag in alarmManager.setRepeating() method

Answer (score 1):

code snippet from AOSP API demo:

```
        // We want the alarm to go off 1hr from now.
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        firstTime += 60 * 60 * 1000;

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        firstTime, 60*60*1000, sender);
```

You may want to follow the [link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.java#114) to view the complete example.

If you what the alarm to go off on the hour (1am, 2am, ...), specify the type as RTC_WAKEUP.

Comment: I dont want the alarm to ring 30 senconds from now.I want it to ring every hr .EG 1 am,2am ,3am, 4am etc .How do i get firstTime  correspondsing tp 1 then?

Comment: Then you should use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`.

Comment: :I am alredy using RTC_WAKEUP .But the problem with RTC_WAKEUP is that when the phone is in power saver mode/ low battery .RTC_WAKEUP  doesnot work sometimes. And hence i posedted the question

Comment: @user93796 if your problem was with power saver mode, why didn't you state that in your question?

Comment: The question still ishow to set alarm starting at specific hr using alarm type  AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP

Answer (score 0):

This will wake up the device to fire the alarm in 1 hour, and every 1 hour after that:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: .First param should be startTime and not interval.So this is wrong

Comment: @user93796 This is from the documentation. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). The exact words are `Here are some examples of using ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.

Wake up the device to fire the alarm in 30 minutes, and every 30 minutes after that:

// Hopefully your alarm will have a lower frequency than this!
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

I think accuya's answer should work, I just improved it that the alarm will ring at the start of each hour.

First, determine the time interval we should skip until the first alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
calendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
long firstAlarmInterval = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

So, if the current time is 7:35, the firstAlarmInterval will represent 25 minutes needed until the first launch at 8:00.

```
long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + firstAlarmInterval;

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    firstTime, 60*60*1000, sender);
```

Answer (score -1):

One hour realtime from now should be this:

`System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 60 * 1000); // 60 minutes`

Comment: I dont think so. currentTimeMillis() give millis since epoch and SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() Returns milliseconds since boot, including time spent in sleep.

Comment: so swap currentTimeMillis() for SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()?

Comment: if the first paramter is AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP then  elapsedRealtime()? should be used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager they got examples using calander as well as boot time and the milliseconds since 1970 epoch unix timestamp