# Uploading Data in Background Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-process

I'd like to upload the current user's location about every 2 minutes when device is awake, or about every 5 minutes when not.

What would be the best way to upload the data in the background (even if app is not running) to a web server?  Is an `IntentService` with `AlarmManager` or something like an `AsyncTask` with a `CountdownTimer` better?

I already know how to get a user's location, and have some practice with `AsyncTask` and `IntentService`. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two better ways that will help you:

**1. When app is awake**

> You can use handler for timer purpose and from the handle call 
>   IntentService for location update. `IntentService` will work in
>   different `Thread` and will finished itself after work completion.
>   [Handler Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/6676466)

**2. When app is not running**

> You have to use `AlarmManager` and from the Alarm Receiver you will
>   call IntentService for location update. [AlarmManager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960057/6676466)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do a task within a specific period of time, I recommend you use a Firebase Job Scheduler and an IntentService.

**Using Firebase Job Dispatcher has a lot of merits.**

> 1. You can give it constraints like  "Do a task only on battery or Do a task when charging and with wifi"
> 2. This has efficiency built-in

You can read more about Firebase Job Dispatcher [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Firebase JobDispatcher.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

It has some advantages over AlarmManager, Jobschedular and GCMNetworkManager. 
Read this [blog](https://medium.com/@KanikaVerma15/schedule-tasks-in-android-all-the-way-from-alarmmanager-to-firebase-job-dispatcher-to-doze-mode-9b53d16bf213) for details.

**Usage:**

> Add the following to your build.gradle's dependencies section:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

> Create a new MyJobService class.

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        // Do some work here

        return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
    }
}
```

> Adding it to the manifest

```
    <service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".MyJobService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

> Scheduling a job

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        // the JobService that will be called
        .setService(MyJobService.class)
        // uniquely identifies the job
        .setTag("my-unique-tag")
        // one-off job
        .setRecurring(false)
        // don't persist past a device reboot
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
        // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
        .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
        // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
        .setReplaceCurrent(false)
        // retry with exponential backoff
        .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
        // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
        .setConstraints(
                // only run on an unmetered network
                Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
                // only run when the device is charging
                Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
        )
        .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```